# How to do schema evolution in aws glue?

Tags: aws-glue

I created a table in aws glue using the crawler, then added a partition in s3 with a different schema and ran the crawler again.

When I look at the partition's schema from the partitions view, it shows the new schema, but that table's schema remains the same.

**How does schema evolution in glue work? When does glue update the table's schema, if at all?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all Depends on how you Configure your crawler. The last Screen ( Configure the crawler's output)  of your crawler would have a Configuration options drop down where you have to specify your requirements depending on you needs. Here is the dialogue below:
[image]